# Trying to both stream and {segmented} store a camera input with a graphic overlay (which must be scaled down to fit)

Tags: ffmpeg, python, streaming

I am trying to write a python program using ffmpeg to capture an input video from a USB camera, overlay a brand graphic on it, and then both store the video as it run and also stream it to WOWza.

No matter what I seem to try, there are problems with initializing the filtergraph or recognizing named pads or otherwise. I think I am just not using escapting correctly along with named pads properly.

Below is a current version with output where I scaled the code back to only capture the video, brand logo and audio and then scale the logo for fit on the video. The next step is a complex filter and overlay filter, but I need to walk first then run.

```
import subprocess 
import time
import os
os.system("sleep 1")
os.system("ffmpeg -y -f v4l2 -framerate 30 -video_size 1280x720 \
-input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video0 \
-f alsa -channels 1 -sample_rate 44100 -i default \
-i /home/dbbarron/Streaming/brand.png -framerate 30 \
-vf scale=160:100 split=2[SplitOut1][SplitOut2]\
[SplitOut1] -f segment -strftime 1 -segment_time 10 out_%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S.mov\
[SplitOut2] -f flv rtmp://4567890449bs.entrypoint.cloud.wowza.com/app-d17Q984B/c9874586453799d314@")
```

and the console output:

```
-/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 13565.321871, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1280x720, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : mono
Input #1, alsa, from 'default':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1686322834.401513, bitrate: 705 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
Input #2, png_pipe, from '/home/dbbarron/Streaming/MBM_Alpha1.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #2:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1464x732 [SAR 5669:5669 DAR 2:1], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[NULL @ 0x1d1c070] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'split=2[SplitOut1][SplitOut2][SplitOut1]'
split=2[SplitOut1][SplitOut2][SplitOut1]: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Don't edit answers. You can comment to reply to answers.

Comment: I have been making progress and I believe that I am close;  Given the entire restructuring of the source, I am posting the latest version immediately below.

Comment: First, if you have an answer, post it. It is completely ok, and encouraged, to answer your own Q. But, don't just add edits to others answers, or post answers that are just "updates" to your question. Format your question however you like, BUT keep it clear and focused on the question. Your goal is to make the question as good as possible in order to get good answers.

Answer (score 0):

When you wish to generate a single output and use it for multiple destinations, you should use the [tee](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#tee-1) muxer generally, as it helps avoid multiple encoding.

```
ffmpeg -y \
-f v4l2 -framerate 30 -video_size 1280x720 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video0 \
-f alsa -channels 1 -sample_rate 44100 -i default \
-i /home/dbbarron/Streaming/brand.png \
-filter_complex "
 [2]scale=160:100[logo];
 [0][logo]overlay=x=0:y=0[v]
" \
-map '[v]' -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -flags:v +global_header -c:a aac \
-f tee \
  "[f=segment:strftime=1:segment_time=10]out_%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S.mov
 | [f=flv]rtmp://4567890449bs.entrypoint.cloud.wowza.com/app-d17Q984B/c9874586453799d314@"
```

Comment: I am now getting the following error at line 18 [2]scale=160:100[logo];
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Try adding the trailing backslash to the lines in between.